# Not able to get count from Search response using Glass Mapper

Tags: glass-mapper, sitecore-query

**Environment details:** Sitecore 9.0.2 with Solr and GlassMapper

I am using the method:

```
  public IEnumerable<TModel> GetAll<TModel>(string query, string language) where TModel : class
        {
            return _service.GetItems<TModel>(new GetItemsByQueryOptions() { Query = Query.New(query), Language = LanguageManager.GetLanguage(language) });
        }
```

The method calls:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(GetItemsOptions options) where T : class;
```

of `ISitecoreService` of GlassMapper.

Then I check the response for `null` and get that it is not null.

Query I am using:

```
/sitecore/content/Global Repository/Regions//*[@@templateid='{28103498-4995-4000-a0db-1d3c2a757c79}' and @@ServiceName=31597]
```

ServiceName is the name of the field I am looking for value 31597.

Further when I try to get the `Count()` or `Any()` on the search result, I never get the response back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code has to be modified a little bit:

- field names in [Sitecore Query](https://doc.sitecore.com/SdnArchive/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.html) should have the only one @ character, the ServiceName field value has to be in quotes and templateid with uppercase A-F letters

```
/sitecore/content/Global Repository/Regions//*[@@templateid='{28103498-4995-4000-A0DB-1D3C2A757C79}' and @ServiceName='31597']
```

- if the items that you expect to read have only shared fields, there is no need to specify a language. You have to set `VersionCount` to `false` instead.

```
return _service.GetItems<TModel>(new GetItemsByQueryOptions() { Query = Query.New(query), VersionCount = false });
```